# What are the technical differences between PUT and POST?

Tags: http, post, put

Leaving aside semantics, meanings, proper and common use cases of PUT and POST (which had been already discussed many times (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest))), what are the technical differences (the way what and how is being sent) between PUT and POST?

Comment: From my experience I don't think there are any technical differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between POST and PUT except different name used in request:

```
POST /resource
```

vs.:

```
PUT /resource/1
```

Since PUT is idempotent, some routers/proxies might treat them differently, but I am not aware of any such cases.